# Read and write below a precise cell in a CSV

Tags: vb.net, csv

I'm stuck on a basic problem. What I want is to parse through a CSV in order to compare some string and write below if I find it.

Precisely, I have a programe where I can drag and drop some button, when I drop this button I want to save it's new location on the first empty cells below the corresponding column.
Here's a sample of my CSV :
[image]

So I substring the .x/.y from my CSV and compare the name from the drop button with each cell with the help of textFieldParser. It seems to work my loop stopped when it find an equal expression.

But here's the problem I don't know how to say to my program to write below it. The first reason I can figured it out is because my parser go until the endOfData and I want it to go until the endOfDat + one row.
The second one is because I don't know if I can use a fieldwriter into textFieldParser, I mean I tried to create a variable with row+1 and write below but nothing happen when I use fileWriter.

now a sample of my code :

```cpp
    Private Sub manageCsv(ByVal sender As Button)

        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("..\..\Pic\csvPic.csv")

            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")

            Dim currentRow As String()
            Dim rowPlusOne As String()
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                    rowPlusUn = MyReader.ReadFields()

                    Dim currentField As String

                    
                    Dim str As String = btnSender.Name.Substring(3)
                    Dim nameDelimited As String
                    Dim x As Integer


                    For Each currentField In currentRow

                        ''Search the corresponding field''
                        x = InStr(currentField, ".")
                        If Not (currentField.Equals("imagefile")) Then ''imagefile is the first index of my csv''
                            nameDelimited = currentField.Substring(0, x) ''substr the extension''
                            If nameDelimited.Equals(str) Then
                                writeCsv("..\..\Image\csvPic.csv", nameDelimited, ",")
                                ''Ofc the "+1" does not work but that was the idea''
                                currentRow(+1) = lblImgName.Text
                                currentRow(+1) = btnSender.Location.ToString 
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                Catch ex As _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try
            End While
        End Using
    End Sub
```

I hope it's clear enough, if not i'll try to elaborate more. Thanks for your help

Comment: Why a csv file? There are easier ways to do this.

Comment: It's an instruction from my teacher, I don't  know why he want that precisely.... But it's a pain.

Comment: Are the column headers the button .Name (or .Text) plus the X and Y coordinates? Is the purpose to recreate the locations after the form is closed?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that. And yes it's supposed to be a mini faceApp so we save & load locations from several img

Answer (score 1):

Show your teacher that there are better ways to do this with a simple text file. The file will only exist if buttons have been moved before in the application. See in line comments.

```
Private ButtonLocation As New Dictionary(Of Button, Point)
Private MouseIsDown As Boolean
Private ptX, ptY As Integer 'Starting point of mouse relative to the button
Private btn As Button 'The button being moved
Private ButtonPath As String = "C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\Code\DroppedButtons.txt"
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Reposition the buttons to where they were dropped in the previous session.
    If File.Exists(ButtonPath) Then
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(ButtonPath) 'returns an array of strings (each line)
        For Each line In lines 'loop though each line in the file
            Dim fields = line.Split(","c) 'The three values on the line are separated by a comma
            Dim b = DirectCast(Controls(fields(0)), Button) 'Change the string Button.Name
            'to an actual Button object by finding it in the controls collection
            'Set the location with the next 2 values on the line
            b.Location = New Point(CInt(fields(1)), CInt(fields(2)))
            'Add the Button and Location to the list
            ButtonLocation.Add(b, b.Location)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
'These three Event procedures are the normal code to Drag and Drop a control
Private Sub Button_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown, Button2.MouseDown
    btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    ptX = e.Location.X
    ptY = e.Location.Y
    MouseIsDown = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove, Button2.MouseMove
    If MouseIsDown Then
        'e.X and e.Y are the coordinates of the Mouse relative to the control (the Button)
        'not the Form or the Screen. 
        btn.Location = New Point(btn.Location.X + e.X - ptX, btn.Location.Y + e.Y - ptY)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseUp, Button2.MouseUp
    MouseIsDown = False
    'When we drop the button with the MouseUp event we record the new location in the list
    RecordButtonLocation(btn, btn.Location)
    btn = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub RecordButtonLocation(Sender As Button, Location As Point)
    'Check if the Button is already in the list
    If ButtonLocation.ContainsKey(Sender) Then
        'Record its new location
        ButtonLocation.Item(Sender) = Location
    Else
        'If it is not in the list add it.
        ButtonLocation.Add(Sender, Location)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    SaveDictionary()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveDictionary()
    If ButtonLocation.Count > 0 Then
        'If there is anything in the list we will create or overwrite the file
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each kv As KeyValuePair(Of Button, Point) In ButtonLocation
            sb.AppendLine($"{kv.Key.Name},{kv.Value.X},{kv.Value.Y}")
        Next
        File.WriteAllText(ButtonPath, sb.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's way better than my previous try where I used 3 textFieldParser and 2 switch... Right now it seem I can save juste one bunch of location due to the writeAllText so I'm trying to modify your code to save several location from the name of there image. Anyway you give me something way cleaner, thanks !

Comment: @Alex Each time a button is moved the new location is saved to the `ButtonList` when the `MouseUp` event. The entire list is saved as the form closes. Are you sure the Handles clause for each of the mouse events includes all the buttons involved?